# Class creating another and returning the pointer. Is it a violation of SOLID principles

Tags: c++, solid-principles

I am not an expert in SOLID principles, therefore got this question.
Does the following violate the SOLID principles? If yes, what would be the ideal solution? (Please check the highlighted code following the example)

```
class IUser
{
public:
    virtual string GetName() = 0;

private:
    string m_strName;
};
class CUser : public IUser
{
public:
    CUser(string strEmail) : m_strEmail(strEmail) {}
    virtual string GetName() {return m_strName;}

    string m_strEmail;
};

class ISignIn
{
public:
    virtual IUser* GetUser(string strEmail) = 0;
};
class CSignIn : public ISignIn
{
public:
    virtual IUser* GetUser(string strEmail)
    {
        return new CUser(strEmail);
    }
};
```

The code I am concerned about is:

```
return new CUser(strEmail);
```

Thanks everybody for answering this question!

Comment: Which part of SOLID are you worried about? The "S" (Single responsibility principle)? Something else? Something more? If it's the "S", then what is the responsibility of the `CSignIn` class? Does it have a single responsibility?

Comment: Oh and while SOLID might be something to strive for, we don't live in an ideal word and it's not always possible to follow SOLID. Sometimes it's just not practical to follow all of the SOLID principles. In other words, you should not worry so much. :)

Comment: Basically, I mean is whether the highlighted code is correct. If not, then what principle it is violating and what is the solution? I am concerned only about the highlighted code.

Comment: Without any specific context or problem besides the little code you show (and that mostly will make us guess about what you're trying to do), I don't see any problem with that single line.

Comment: it doesnt make sense trying to follow principles (whatever they may be) just for the sake of the principle. They were invented to avoid very concrete problems (and sometimes even come at the price of small disadvantages). You will always have to make a compromise and its hard/impossible to help you without knowing more context and what those classes are supposed to be used for

Comment: I was not sure if it was Okay to create the concrete class directly as it's done here. Thanks all!